# Xubuntu (XFCE) application finder suggestions

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, thunar

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 and rely pretty heavily on the Application Finder, which I call using ALT-F2. It's a nice way to start GUI programs when you know their names, especially since when you type the first few letters it suggests applications you probably intend on starting. But in this case it is not so helpful. When I type 'thu' to try to call the file manager, Thunar, its only suggestions are 'thunderbird' and 'thunar-volman-settings'. How do I get it to suggest 'thunar' instead of/as well as 'thunar-volman-settings'?

This behavior seems odd seeing as how most users usually want the file manager and not the file manager settings.

Comment: Wow, odd one.  On my Arch Xfce machine when I get to "th" it lists thunar, thunar-settings and thunar-volman-settings.  Is there any chance one of the optional dependencies for Thunar is required for this to work?  Looooong shot I know.  I'm using version 4.12.1 of Xfce and Thunar version 1.6.10.

Answer (score 1):

Fuzzy search has been added upstream in git (https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-appfinder/commit/?id=486a9ae055d3e4b8baf5c5648587b42535365185) as a result of bug 10393 (https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10393). It hasn't yet been officially released, so you'll need to build from source if you want that functionality now.